# Dlib installed but cannot open it- Mac M1

Tags: python, dlib

I installed the dlib package on my Mac M1 through anaconda, and when I type "conda list" in the terminal, I can see "dlib" being installed. But when I type "dlib --version" in the Terminal, I have this message "zsh: command not found: dlib". Furthermore, when I open Spyder, or Jupyter, and when I try to import dlib, the Kernel crashes.
Can anyone help me with this? I have been struggling with this issue for so long...
Thanks for the support!

Comment: dlib is a module that you have added to the python libraries, it is not a stand-alone application. Therefore, you cannot call 'dlib' in this way. dlib is included in your python script by tying 'import dlib'.

Comment: The problem is, hen I try "import dlib" on Spyder, I have this error message: 
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib'"
Am I missing something?
When I do "conda list" on my Terminal, I still can see "dlib" being installed
Am I missing something?

Comment: Is Spyder using the correct environment? Have you tried just running Python from the terminal (with the environment active) and importing the library?

Comment: any solution? I have M1.

Answer (score 1):

solved it by manually linking the libpng library for me:

```
brew install libpng
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpng/1.6.37/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpng/1.6.37/lib
pip3 install dlib --force-reinstall
```

(replace 1.6.37 by your installed version of libpng)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I uninstalled anaconda, reinstalled it, and I used pip install (cmake, boost, dlib) instead of Conda install. Both dlib and face_recognition worked.

Comment: what is the solution? I Have a macbook pro woth m1.

Comment: pip install cmake
pip install boost
pip install dlib==19.22